# I recommended that the OP's question was not right for SO

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question

...was I wrong? [Workflow for obfuscated PHP code with PHP protect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25771597/1011527)

I am being taken to task by a reasonably high rep Stack Overflovian, [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter), and I will be glad to rescind my recommendations to the OP if the Meta Stack Overflovians indicate to me that I have made a mistake.

Comment: None of Ira's comments are still there...

Comment: He always has his spam-motor running, nowadays he's selling a PHP obfuscator too.  Bizarre idea, surely sales are not great.  Just ignore him.

Comment: When I offered to and then posted this on Meta he seemed to be skittish. That's when I read his profile. and figured out that arguing with him was not in my best interest @Deduplicator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is marginal.  It is a practical scenario, but it's not really well-enough defined (it isn't a practical single problem).  Right now an answer has to cover every debugging activity imaginable -- that should rightly be closed for being too broad.

On the other hand, matching a stack trace logged in the obfuscated code back to the original would be a valid question.  Or anything else that is a single well-defined but generalizable problem.

Answer (score 25):

Ah, yes.  Ira Baxter.  Let's just say that he has a really colorful history here.

The OP can go ahead and ask his question on Programmers, if he must.  But he should be prepared for them taking him to task for not keeping a copy of the de-obfuscated code, so that he could make changes. Keeping a copy of the de-obfuscated code is the only legitimate answer to his question, and if he no longer has de-obfuscated code, then he needs to de-obfuscate what he has.

Comment: Keeping a copy of the pre-obfuscated code is not an answer; it's necessary but not sufficient.  It still remains to debug that code using information from the obfuscated environment, and that appears to be the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/256025/1204